# Shader to pixi.js animation

Tags: javascript, glsl, shader, pixi.js

i'm trying to connect my shader to pixi.js canvas.
I think i have it the right way but i get an error when i apply my shader to anything in my canvas.

i think i got a problem with the function new PIXI.AbstractFilter

Here is my code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PixiJS Shaders</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        canvas {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/pixi.js/3.0.7/pixi.js'></script>

<script id="fragShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    precision mediump float;
    uniform vec2            iResolution;
    uniform float           iGlobalTime;
    uniform sampler2D       iChannel0;
    uniform sampler2D       iChannel1;

    void main()
    {
        vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy;
        float timeanim = iGlobalTime * 0.5;
        vec4 mask = texture2D(iChannel1, uv) * sin(timeanim) * 5.;
        vec4 text = texture2D(iChannel0, uv + vec2( 0., mask.r) );
        text.rgb -= abs(mask.r);
        if(uv.y > 1. || uv.y < 0. ) text.rgb = vec3(0.);

        gl_FragColor = text;
    }

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var width = 600;
  var height = 600;
  var renderer = new PIXI.autoDetectRenderer( width, height );

  /*Aliases*/

  var p_container          = PIXI.Container,
      p_autoDetectRenderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer,
      p_loader             = PIXI.loader,
      p_sprite             = PIXI.Sprite;
  var mask = p_sprite.fromImage( "image/displacement-map.png" ); // mask
  var img = p_sprite.fromImage( "http://i.imgur.com/2yYayZk.png" ); // sprite
  var uniforms = {};
  uniforms.iGlobalTime = {
    type : '1f',
    value: 0.0
  };
  uniforms.iResolution = {
    type: 'v2',
    value: {
      x : width,
      y : height
    }
  };
  uniforms.iChannel1 = { //  mask
    type: 'sampler2D',
    value : mask
  };
  uniforms.iChannel0 = { //  image
    type: 'sampler2D',
    value : img
  };
  console.log( uniforms );
  document.body.appendChild( renderer.view );

  var stage = new PIXI.Container();

  var logo = p_sprite.fromImage( "http://www.goodboydigital.com/pixijs/pixi_v3_github-pad.png" );
  logo.x = width / 2;
  logo.y = width / 2;
  logo.anchor.set( 0.5 );
  stage.addChild( logo )

  var shaderCode = document.getElementById( 'fragShader' ).textContent;
  console.log( shaderCode );
  var smokeShader = new PIXI.AbstractFilter( '',shaderCode, uniforms );
  console.log( smokeShader );
  stage.filters = [ smokeShader ];

  animate()

  function animate()
  {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    renderer.render( stage );
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: what's the error you get?